# Report collapses by default. Do you know how to avoid this?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

Per screenshot below, there are two images.

The top image shows the report as it looks like when a user runs the report.

Notice the (+) sign. That + sign collapses the report and hides the values.

The bottom image shows the report when expanded.

To expand the report, the user must click the + sign which changes to - (minus sign) and displays the values within the report.

[image]

Is there a way to modify reportviewer to display reports as soon as a user runs it?

What we are trying to do is group surveys by Location.

Each location displays the surveys taken at that location, by various users and their test scores.

We are using VS2010 to build the reports.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you already have the drilldown functionality set up correctly so you just need to make sure the items involved have certain attributes set appropriately when the report loads.

To get everything expanded by default, you need to make sure that the detail row's **Hidden** attribute is set to *False*, i.e. show when the report loads, and the toggle item, i.e. the *Loc* group textbox, has its **InitialToggleState** set to *True*, i.e. make sure the textbox has a **(-)** sign when the report loads.

Comment: first sorry for responding this late. I had to run an errand.

Unless, I am doing it wrong which is possible, I can see the sign change from + to - but the expansion isn't happening.

When you say, detail row's Hidden attribute, what is detail row? 

Maybe that's what is missing.

The row that isn't tht title row, has attribute as Hidden already.

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but I'm struggling with the exact same problem. @Ian Preston: Are there any other parameters to watch out for? Hidden is false on all my Table items, and the InitialToggleState seems to only change the icon from + to -. But not the state itself. Using VS 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Never mind, got it! Right Click on the according row (or column) and then there's a menu entry with "Visibility".

Comment: @Mathew, I have the same problem.  But, I couldn't see the "Visibility" in my column.  All I can see is a disabled "Column Visibility" when I right click my tablix column.  How did you do it?

Comment: @Ian Preston I was struggling to figure out where to set the InitialToggleState, so thanks for explicitly mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

Change the visibility of the child group to "Show".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MWuK.png)